# Testing expo-linear-gradient in react native ,throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, expo

My Error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

  at requireNativeViewManager (node_modules/expo-modules-core/src/NativeViewManagerAdapter.native.tsx:28:49)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/src/NativeLinearGradient.android.tsx:49:34)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/src/LinearGradient.tsx:4:1)
```

My Presets :

```
 projects: [
{ "preset": "jest-expo/ios" },
{ "preset": "jest-expo/android" },
{ "preset": "jest-expo/web" },
```

],

Component:

```
 <LinearGradient
      colors={colorsArray}
      style={{
        ...uikitStyles.progressBar,
        height: heightHandler(height).height,
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        width: `${newWidth}%`,
      }}
      end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
      testID="gradient-test"
    />
```

[Screen Shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxiZS.jpg)

Im using '@testing-library/react-native' to write the test cases, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check jest-expo version and expo. They should match.
2. Check your jest.config.js (original answer https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8527#issuecomment-640103212):
   The issue was that I was using @testing-library/react-native as my jest preset instead of jest-expo. Adding the jest-expo preset alongside the testing-library preset to my jest.config.js managed to resolve it:

   ```
   const expoPreset = require('jest-expo/jest-preset');

   module.exports = {
      ...expoPreset,
      preset: "@testing-library/react-native",
   }
   ```